# Overriding Click listener methods in Android

Tags: android, overriding, customdialog

interface Class:

```
    public interface CustomDialogMethods {

        public void btn_yes();
        public void btn_no();
    }
```

MainActivity implements from CustomDialogMethods it must override custom's button okey and cancel methods;

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity implements CustomDialogMethods {

    @Override
        public void btn_yes() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    @Override
        public void btn_no() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
}
```

and my custom Dialog Class, its have okey and cancel button:

```
    public class CustomWorking extends Activity {

         void CustomDialogWorker(final Dialog dialog,int layout,int b_no,int b_yes) {

                dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                dialog.setContentView(layout);

                Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(b_yes);    
                Button dialogButtonno = (Button) dialog.findViewById(b_no);        

                dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                dialogButtonno.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });          

                dialog.show();           
            }
```

whats best way to override my dialog okey button and cancel button in MainActivity class with interface methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass your context to CustomDialogWorker method and trigger btn_yes() btn_no()

```
CustomDialogWorker(dialog,layout,b_no,b_yes, this)
```

OR

Add this code in your **MainActivity**

```
 listener = new CustomDialogMethods() {
        @Override
        public void btn_yes() {

        }

        @Override
        public void btn_no() {

        }
    };
```

pass the listener

```
CustomDialogWorker(dialog,layout,b_no,b_yes, listner);
```

inside CustomDialogWorker method

trigger methods

```
listner.btn_yes();
listener.btn_no();
```